# Closed form for $\sqrt{x +\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^3+\cdots}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, closed-form

If this series $S_x$ converges for some $x$, can we find its closed form expression?

$$ S_x=\sqrt{x +\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^3+\sqrt{x^4+\cdots}}}} $$

For $x=1$, it's easy and we have,

$$ S_1 = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}} \implies S_1^2=S_1+1 \implies S_1=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$$

But I can't solve in an expression of $x$ for general case.

If the closed form is not known, can we prove that it does not exist ?

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe it has a closed form?

Comment: See [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683762), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3396959), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3406932), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3747684)

Comment: @Ennar Thanks. I don't know why they didn't showed up as related duplicates while I was writing the question.

Comment: @BrianMoehring No, I am not sure about that. See my first line : *"can we find its closed form expression?"* Thanks

Comment: @Sil Thanks. I don't know why they didn't appeared while I writting the question.

Comment: @An_Elephant, unfortunately, the search algorithm on MSE is far from ideal, many users use https://approach0.xyz/search/ to search up maths.

Comment: @Ennar Thanks for link. Anyway, in any of the post , the conclusion is that we don't know it has closed form. Is there a proof that it don't have a closed form ?

Comment: @An_Elephant, I can't tell you. If it's important to you, I'd ask a separate question (with all of these references) after I studied these links and gave a thought about it, and very importantly, explain in detail why the closed form is important to you and possibly others, but I'd guess it's not an easy question and you might not get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @Ennar Okay thanks. I'll edit the question accordingly.